# Measure time spent in each iterate in a while loop in java or android

Tags: android, loops, while-loop

I want to know how long spent for execute an iterate in a `while` loop? More precisely I write a while loop for execute a download task and write data to file and I want to measure download speed every time that loop goes to next iterate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use a calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

```
List <Long> elapsedTimes = new ArrayList<>();   //contains the time taken for all iterations.
long startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
long elapsedTime = startTime;
for (... your for loop)
{ 
    ... //do your stuff ...
    long currTime = Calendar.getInstance.getTimeInMillis();
    elapsedTimes.add(currTime - elapsedTime);
    elapsedtime = currTime;

}
long endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

long totalTime= endtime - startTime.
```